# I'm building a bubble pane. What can I do to reduce static pressure?

Tags: pressure, statics, fluid-statics

I'm building [a bubble pane](https://media.giphy.com/media/l41lJRWNlgGWPUxAk/giphy.gif), just for decoration in my home, using some patio door glass panes and an aquarium air pump. Soon into my testing, I learned what static pressure is. When I fill it up, even just to a few feet, the glass begins to bow and makes me reluctant to add more. Ideally, I'd like to fill it to the top.

[image]

Static pressure depends on depth, gravity, and fluid density. So reducing the width or the thickness wouldn't help, and I can't go to the moon...but maybe I could use alcohol or oil or something? Maybe there's some trick to "separate" the single body into many (while still permitting bubbles to rise) to reduce height or something?

Is there anything I can do to get the bubble effect I want without reducing height or requiring significant reinforcement?

Comment: The effect of alcohol or oil is minimal as their densities are also close to $1\:\mathrm{kg/L}$. Your only hope is to use thicker glass.

Comment: Might [diy.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful. What you're doing is very dangerous. Large pressures and forces are present here and you're lucky that the ordinary (1/8" thick?) glass panes didn't shatter and throw glass shards at you and your family. Look at what you've made. All that water trapped between the glass panes has no strength so it just wants to go down in the direction of gravity. And the water at the bottom of your contraption is being pushed down by all the water on top of it. That results in a lot of pressure at the bottom. If the water in the picture shown is about 4 feet high, then that translates into about (4 feet/33 feet) = 0.12 atmospheres of pressure which translates into (14.7 lbs/sq in)*(0.12)= 1.8 lbs per sq inch. So that's almost 2 pounds of force pushing on each and every square inch of "patio glass pane" at the bottom of the display. That's a disaster waiting to happen.

There's a reason why most aquariums you see in your local pet shop tend to be wider than they are tall. Making an aquarium wider doesn't increase the pressure at the bottom of the tank. Making an aquarium taller does. And +4 feet tall aquariums are relatively rare because they do require lots of additional strengthening (e.g., thicker glass, heavier reinforcement). A +4 foot high aquarium is NOT going to use 1/8" glass panes. The glass or plexiglass will be much, much thicker than that.

Out of curiosity I did a web search for "tall aquariums" and found a company which features a number of tall aquariums here: [Midwest Tropical Aquariums](http://store.midwest-tropical.com/brands/Midwest-Tropical.html?page=1&sort=featured). Note that their really tall aquariums of 80" tall (=6'8" high) tend to cost over $1000 since they undoubtedly require extra-thick glass and extra reinforcement. Do yourself and your family a favor by playing it safe and going with a company which already has the expertise and experience for designing and building tall aquariums.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to take a chance, try this.

I notice that you have a horizontal spacer. Using a glass bit, drill a pair of 1/4 inch holes in the panes under the spacer (each at about 1/3 the length of the spacer), then drill out matching holes in the spacer. Using liberal quantities of silicone sealant, run a pair of 1/4 inch bolts through the spacers/panes, and let the bolts take the strain. Make sure to use good-sized washers under the bolt heads and nuts.

Comment: The glass is tempered. Drilling is not possible.